# Ubuntu 22.04.3 not properly recognizing trackpad on CF-30 wrongly detected as PS/2 generic mouse

Tags: touchpad

Ubuntu 22.04.3 not properly detecting trackpad on my CF-30. Wrongly detected as ps/2 generic mouse. No trackpad shows with `xinput -list`

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]

⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]

```
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ Fujitsu Component USB Touch Panel         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]

↳ Panasonic Laptop Support                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1500006/edit) your question and provide the output of `xinput -list`